# OpenVPN client на Windows не правильно маршрутизирует трафик

Tags: windows, маршрутизация, vpn, openvpn, route

Есть впн сервер на CentOS. После импортирования файла конфигурации vpn.ovpn для стандартного клиента на Ubuntu и других линуксах всё работает как надо. Когда я импортирую этот файл конфигурации для клиента OpenVPN на Windows, то подключение к впн происходит успешно, выход в интернет есть, а вот внешний IP не меняется. Нужно что бы менялся, так же как это происходит при обычном импорти конфига на Linux'e Я так понимаю что есть какая то проблема с маршрутизацией на windows (на разных компах с виндой пробовал импортировать этот файл, но проблема сохраняется та же). Как я могу исправить эту ситуацию для компов на Windows??

Моя конфигурация на сервере openvpn.conf

```
port 1196
proto udp
dev tun
ca /opt/EasyRSA-3.0.8/pki/ca.crt
cert /opt/EasyRSA-3.0.8/pki/issued/vpn1.shogo.ru.crt
key /opt/EasyRSA-3.0.8/pki/private/vpn1.shogo.ru.key
crl-verify /opt/EasyRSA-3.0.8/pki/crl.pem
dh /opt/openvpn-v2.5.3/etc/keys/dh.pem
server 192.168.160.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /opt/openvpn-v2.5.3/etc/ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.17.11.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN example.com"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN dev2"
push "route 172.17.11.1 255.255.255.255"
push "route 172.17.11.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir /opt/openvpn-v2.5.3/etc/ccd
keepalive 30 120
cipher AES-256-GCM
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-v2.5.3-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-v2.5.3.log
log-append  /vag/log/openvpn/openvpn-v2.5.3.log
verb 3
```

Моя конфигурация для клиента (vpn.ovpn):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn1.example.com 1196
remote vpn2.example.com 1196
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

auth-nocache
mssfix
verb 3

remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256
```